# UnicodeDecodeError when installing via pip install virtualenv

Tags: pip, virtualenv, setuptools

**virtualenv 15.0.1**

**Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS**

**locale:**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

This executes perfectly (virtualenv is deactivated):

```
root@simple_project:~# pip install django-crequest==2016.3.16
```

But when I activate the virtualenv:

```
(photoarchive) root@simple_project:~/venv# pip install django-crequest==2016.3.16
Collecting django-crequest==2016.3.16
  Using cached django-crequest-2016.3.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g5etn1cn/django-crequest/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        license=open('LICENSE').read(),
      File "/root/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 204: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-g5etn1cn/django-crequest/
```

Could you help me understand what is going on and how to cope with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package seems to has non-ascii text in its `LICENSE` file and something (`pip`?) doesn't like it. Try to set `LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"`.